# firrtl.Driver is deprecated - but what should we use instead?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I've updated rocket-chip today and noticed that FIRRTL now says this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: firrtl.Driver is deprecated since 1.2!
Please switch to firrtl.stage.FirrtlStage
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Okay, fair enough, I presume we have to update what we pass to the invocation of FIRRTL:

```
FIRRTL ?= java -Xmx3G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M $(FIRRTL_PROFILE_SWITCH)  -cp $(FIRRTL_JAR) firrtl.Driver
```

However naively switching `firrtl.Driver` to `firrtl.stage.FirrtlStage` didn't work:

```
Error: Main method not found in class firrtl.stage.FirrtlStage, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

What should we do to avoid this deprecation warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my bad, the deprecation warning needs to be updated. You may (optionally) switch to `firrtl.stage.FirrtlMain` if you so choose. See [freechipsproject/rocket-chip#1984](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/pull/1984) for how to update Rocket Chip. I'll get a PR in to fix this on the FIRRTL side.

There was some flux between `FirrtlStage` and `FirrtlMain`. The reasoning was that not every stage had to have a main function.

If you want more info on the whole Stage/Phase refactor that's percolating through Chisel, FIRRTL, and related projects see [freechipsproject/FIRRTL#1005](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/pull/1005) and (not merged yet) [freechipsproject/FIRRTL#1079](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/pull/1079).